# How to change Y - axis scale to uneven?

Tags: r, plot, line, scatter-plot, radix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBkBa.png)I have data to plot for the range of 0-70 for y-axis.
But the main plot is up to y = 5, which should be in 75% of the plot/scale and the other data from 5-70 should acquire just 25% of the plot.
I need to show the marked part in my plot.

I tried few things but no success, help please!
Thank you

Comment: Is ```ylim = c(0, 5)``` what you're looking for? Setting this option in ```plot(...)``` will cut the y axis at y = 5. I'm not quite sure what you want to do, though. If you want to show the complete range but make the lower range values better visible, try using a log scale

Comment: Just set the argument `ylim` of your plot to the region you want displayed. You can write `plot(data, ylim=c(0,5))`. Then, your y axis will only reach to 5 and some points will not be shown as they are above.

Answer (score 0):

You could log transform your y value. see this example with the pressure dataset:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(x = pressure$temperature, y = pressure$pressure, type = "l")
plot(x = pressure$temperature, y = log(pressure$pressure), type = "l")
```

[image]

Comment: Actually adding log would defer actual plot.

Comment: I want points like 0,0.5,1,1.5,.......4.5,5,25,45,65,85.